# Updating PHP+Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, debian-wheezy

I'm using Debian Wheezy x64.
I've installed PHP and Apache via "apt-get install php5 apache2" with all dependencies.
But as Debian packages are so slow in updating, I want to reinstall PHP and Apache manually with the newest version. To do that I'll purge all php5 and apache2 packages.

Now I'm wondering whether the versions from php.net and httpd.apache.org replace all those packages like php5-dev, php5-cli, libapache2-mod-php5 and so on?

Comment: It would be trivial for you to go and look at them. Why are you asking this question here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those packages in Debian. Well, I'll just test it.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to use a PPA. Though PPAs normally meant for Ubuntu users, but since Ubuntu is a Debian-derivative, [you can use PPAs with Debian](http://www.astarix.co.uk/2011/05/using-ubuntu-ppa-packages-with-debian-or-crunchbang/).

- [PHP PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5)
- [Apache PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/apache2)